# How to connect Janusgraph 0.4.0 to COSMOS DB (Cassandra API)?

Tags: azure

I am trying to connect to Azure Cosmos DB (Cassandra API) from janusgraph (on Azure VM) using the below property file

**The janusgraph-cql.properties file**

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
graph.set-vertex-id = false
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=xx.xx.xxx.xxxx
storage.port=10350
storage.cassandra.keyspace=janusgraph
storage.username=hipcosmosdb-cass
storage.password=***************
storage.cassandra.ssl.enabled=true
storage.cassandra.ssl.truststore.location=/data/certs/cacerts.jks
storage.cassandra.ssl.truststore.password=*****
```

I am able to connect to the data base running the java quickstart code from the same VM.

**The quickstart code config file**

```
###Cassandra endpoint details on cosmosdb
cassandra_host=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
cassandra_port=10350
cassandra_username=hipcosmosdb-cass
cassandra_password=************
ssl_keystore_file_path=/data/certs/cacerts.jks
ssl_keystore_password=******
```

The relevant port rules are added.
However, the below error remains.

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: xxxxxxxxxx:10350 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/40.89.132.238:10350] Operation timed out))
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:268)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:107)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1652)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1571)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:208)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:376)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:355)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:305)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.initializeSession(CQLStoreManager.java:302)
        at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.<init>(CQLStoreManager.java:174)
```